# How to use pcse.base_classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the first time, I wanted to use the pcse package. I installed the Requirements and dependencies according to the document and also test the installation of the package, but when I use the following command in the main code:

```
from pcse.base_classes import ParameterProvider
```

it gives an error:

> No module named 'pcse.base_classes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used that module but

```
from pcse.base import ParameterProvider
```

works for me. Here are the methods it provides:

```
>>> dir(ParameterProvider)
['_MutableMapping__marker', '__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_cropdata', '_iter', '_maps', '_ncrops_activated', '_override', '_sitedata', '_soildata', '_test_uniqueness', '_timerdata', '_unique_parameters', 'clear', 'clear_override', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'logger', 'next', 'pop', 'popitem', 'set_active_crop', 'set_override', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

They changed it in [5.4.2-3-g3efc1fd](https://github.com/ajwdewit/pcse/commit/3efc1fd2f0a329b716a73e337f6c5c68497f7d49).

Comment: the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: On StackOverflow you thank by accepting the answer. See [What should I
do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)